# Add all jars from a folder to jmeter classpath

Tags: jmeter, classpath

I have a CI server dumping several application jars and their various dependencies in a single folder. I'm trying to then run a jmeter test with all the jars in jmeter's classpath.

I can set jmeter's `user.classpath` property to a (semi-)colon separated list of individual jars, but using a wild card doesn't seem to be supported. Is there a way I can add the entire folder worth of jars to jmeter's classpath?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [How to Use JUnit With JMeter guide:](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)

> You can also “tell” JMeter to look into additional locations via the “user.classpath” property. This property lives in the “user.properties” file under the /bin folder of your JMeter installation. It can take the following values:
>
> - Single jar file:   user.classpath=/Projects/junit/test1.jar
> - Multiple jar files:  user.classpath=/Projects/junit/test1.jar;/Projects/junit/test2.jar
> - A folder:   user.classpath=/Projects/junit
> - Any combination of the above. Individual classpath entries need to be separated by semicolon or colon depending on underlying operating system

The post is about JUnit, however class loading and classpath configuration is applicable to any external .jar files.

Remember that changing classpath is not dynamic process and you'll need to restart JMeter in order to pick any new jars or a property change.

Comment: I had tried `user.classpath=/Projects/junit` but it didn't pick up the jars until I explicitly listed the individual jars. Maybe it is something that changed between versions. Will try with a newer version.

Comment: It's recommended to use latest version of JMeter as it has performance improvements, bug fixes, etc. The approach works fine for JMeter 2.13

Comment: Yup, verified, works in 2.13. I believe I was using 2.9 before that. Thank you.