# JMeter not recognizing classpath in user.properties

Tags: java, jmeter, wso2, classpath

I am using JMeter version 5.0 r and I am following [this tutorial]
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Point-to-Point+Messaging#865c10b8d4d64ac688d6a0799cfb6012),

[image]

**jndiqueues.properties**

```
# register some connection factories
# connectionfactory.[jndiname] = [ConnectionURL]
connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5675'

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.FirstQueue = myfirstqueue
```

when I am running this JMS publisher I am getting error as:

```
Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory  [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory ]
```

This jar is already there in lib folder still I added want to add it in classpath because it was giving this error. So I edited `user.properties` file, like mentioned in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399808/add-all-jars-from-a-folder-to-jmeter-classpath):

```
user.classpath=../classes;../lib;../app1/jar1.jar;../app2/jar2.jar;../lib/andes-client-4.0.0.jar
```

But still I am getting same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using full paths in `user.properties` rather than relative paths? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, I have tried `user.classpath=../classes;../lib;../app1/jar1.jar;../app2/jar2.jar;E:/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/andes-client-4.0.0.jar` but it is still giving same error. I have added JMS screenshot also

Answer (score 0):

If you copied `andes-client-4.0.0.jar` to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation there is no need to set up `user.classpath` property, JMeter will automatically pick it up.

Remember that you need to **restart JMeter** for any property change application and when you add .jars under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), otherwise the changes will not be picked up.

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

You can also add the libraries to JMeter Classpath at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level like:

[image]

in that case JMeter restart will not be required

Answer (score 0):

1. try the same you did but using absolute class paths instead of relative ones
2. What it worked for me was to use:

   ```
   <propertiesJMeter>
       <search_paths>${project.basedir}/some_path</search_paths>
       <user.classpath>${project.basedir}/some_path</user.classpath>
    </propertiesJMeter>
   ```

Hope it helps